# ERROR - 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'

Tags: asp.net, string, vb.net, visual-studio, integer

I am trying to enter data for each row into a SQL Database table but keep getting this error

```
'Conversion from string "VisitorID" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'
```

This is the code i have got

```
Dim url As String


        url = bcintegration.GetInfoForIntegration(DropDownList1.SelectedValue).Rows(0)(1)

        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = CType(3072, SecurityProtocolType)
            Dim json As String = (New WebClient).DownloadString(url)
            IntegrationGridView.DataSource = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(json)
            IntegrationGridView.DataBind()

        For Each row As GridViewRow In IntegrationGridView.Rows


            If DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "SignInSystemEntityIntegration" Then

THIS IS THE LINE WITH THE ERROR - bcintegration.SubmitDataForSignInSystemEntity(CInt(row.Cells("VisitorID").Text), Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, True, False, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, 1)
            Else
            End If



        Next
```

The 'Nothing' statement is just for testing - that will have data later on.

Please Help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't get to just make up methods or properties on the fly. The [`Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecellcollection.item?view=netframework-4.8) property that you're getting here:

```vb
row.Cells("VisitorID")
```

only accepts an ordinal index, not a name. The documentation, which you should have read, tells you that and Intellisense would have told you that when you wrote the code. The error message is also telling you that. You need to provide a column index, not a column name.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert String to int by doing like this:

1.For C#: `int val = Int32.Parse("12");`

2.For VB.NET: `Dim val as Integer = CInt("12")`

Here you can find all Type Conversion Functions (Visual Basic).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx

How to Convert a String to a Number (C# Programming Guide).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx